# Is there any way to copy from excel and paste into jqgrid

Tags: php, jqgrid

Is there any way to copy data cells from excel and paste into jqgird or opensource grids so that is saves to database.

Comment: You mean multiple data cells, correct? What do you mean by "opensource"?

Comment: yeah,i made typo opensource grids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By googling at last i got

http://www.vinylfox.com/datadrop-drag-grid-data-from-spreadsheet/

It was nice extension of extjs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library to read Excel documents in PHP.

Comment: I want to paste the data from excel to grid so that the data in the cells save the data in mysql database